# Reduction - Subset sum problem to path sum problem

Tags: path, reduction, subset-sum

I am trying to reduce the decision subset sum problem to decision path sum problem but I can not see the relation between them.
The subset sum problem is about deciding if there is a subset in the set S where the subset sum equal k.
The path sum problem is about deciding if there is a path from point (1,1) to point (n,n) in a nxn grid where the path sum equal k. The path can be created by moving from (i, j) to either (i+1, j) or (i,j+1) but at one and only one step during the movement, you can go back to the place it just came from.
Notes: All the integers are poistive integers.